# How can I combine multiple lists in a group by?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

If I have a group by query and I want to combine multiple lists how can I combine the lists into one. Say for a object session with properties class list. Ideally remove any duplicate values from list too.

Example

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.SchoolId).Select( a => new SchoolObject { 

    // this query doesnt work but I r.ListIWantToGroup is a list, that I would like to combine with other lists in group by
    // and if possible also eliminate duplicates from lists by one of objects properties, note list is filled with complex object and not primitive type of so I dont know if thats possible, item I would want to prevent duplicates on would be r.ListIWantToGroup[index].Value
    ExampleList = a.Select( r => r.ListIWantToGroup)

}).ToList();
```

```
//Example Model for List

public class ListIWantToGroup {
    public string PropertyName {get; set; }
    public string Value {get; set; }
}

// Example Model for object
public class SchoolObject{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int Id{get; set; }
    public List<itemIwanttogroup> ExampleList {get; set;)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include (the relevant parts of) your model.

Comment: What is `session`? Is it a list of `SchoolObject`? Where's `SchoolId`? Where's `ExampleList`? Please make sure your code is a [repro].

Comment: Updated it to make it more clear, school id not relevant to question just included it to show it is a groupby query, session just variable name

Comment: more details are needed. what is `data`? how to define it?

Comment: I'm only asking about combining r.ListIWanttoGroup into exampleList

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `SelectMany`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your aim is, though it sounds like you're trying to remove duplicates based on a single property of an object

Let's talk about GroupBy; hopefully it help further you towards figuring out what you need to do

GroupBy operates on a single input list, lets say a 1 dimensional array, and it increases the number of dimensions by 1. The output of grouping a 1D array is conceptually a 2D array

You have some schools:

```
[
  { SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A" },
  { SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A2" },
  { SchoolId: 2, Name: "School B" },
]
```

You group this by SchoolId. The output is bunch of IGroupings, each of which is conceptually an array/list of the original objects. There is one IGrouping for each unique key. Each IGrouping contains all the objects that share that key

In the sample above, two schools have ID 1 and one school has ID 2.  The output of the grouping will be two IGroupings. One of them has a Key of 1 and contains two school objects. The other has a Key of 2 and contains one school object

```
[
  {
    Key: 1,
    self: [
      { SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A" },
      { SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A2" }
    ]
  },

  
  {
    Key: 2,
    self: [
      { SchoolId: 2, Name: "School B" }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's not so easy to represent in json because json doesn't have a concept of an object that has a Key property and is also a list of objects, but imagine that the "self" above is the list of schools that would arise from enumerating over a particular grouping

Your 1D array has gone jagged 2D:

```
//before
[
  school A,
  school A2,
  school B
]

//after
[
  [school A,school A2],
  [school B]
]
```

When you run a Select against this new jagged 2D thing you're selecting IGrouping objects that represent the inner lists. To this end I typically alias the input to the select as `g` because it's a grouping (IGrouping). The members of the group share a key.

Let's pull just the first school per id:

```
schools.GroupBy(s => s.SchoolId).Select(g =>
  g.First()  
)
```

Remember that `g` is effectively a list of schools so `g.First()` here is a single school. The output of selecting the first from each inner list is that you get one school per Id. School A2 is lost:

```
[
  //{
    //Key: 1,
    //self: [
      { SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A" }
      //{ SchoolId: 1, Name: "School A2" } 
    //]
  //}

  
  //{
    //Key: 2,
    //self: [
      { SchoolId: 2, Name: "School B" },
    //]
  //}
]
```

The output of `g.First()` is a School, so the output of Select is an `IEnumerable<School>` - all the groupings are gone, School A is kept, as is School B, and School A2 is gone

Had you done `g.Last()`, Schhol A2 would be kept and School A would be lost

---

The opposite operation of a GroupBy is conceptually a SelectMany; you give it an inner list in a 2D and it combines all the inner lists into one list, going from 2D to 1D again. It was mentioned in the comments but I don't think it'll be what you want because it puts you back to where you were/undoes  the GroupBy. You might use it if you were doing something like "list of schools, group by x, order each grouping by y descending, take top z records, expand 2D back to 1D list"